# How to add a custom validator if a certain annotation is present

Tags: javafx

I'm using [FXForm2](https://github.com/dooApp/FXForm2) to automatically generate forms for my Java beans.

When I annotate a `String` property with `@Size(min=2, max=10)` FXForm automatically adds the corresponding validator to the corresponding field.

I would like to have a similar functionality for the `@Before` annotation on `Date` properties.  How can I add a custom annotation-validator mapping to all of my FXForms?

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom constraints as explained in [Creating custom constraints](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-using) and use these annotations on your bean. The FXForm will automatically validate those constraints and show any reported error message.

You can find an example of such custom constraints in the [FXForm demo](https://github.com/dooApp/FXForm2/tree/master/demo/src/main/java/com/dooapp/fxform/validation)